# string[,] array of string arrays equivalent in C

Tags: c#, c, arrays

In C#, if I were to create an array of string arrays it is easy as doing:

```
string[,] array = new string[50,7];
```

How would I go about doing that in C? I do understand that I should make use of pointers but what I have come up with doesn't seem to work properly.

```
char *array[50][7];
```

Please note that I'm not looking to set the elements to constant values, I need to be able to access them/set them in the program again either by means of using the `scanf()` function or simply with `=` if possible. What is the simplest way of achieving this?

EDIT: Am I doing something wrong here? The following very simple example crashes the program:

```
char *username;

printf("Username: ");
scanf("%s", &username);

array[0][0] = malloc(strlen(username) + 1);
strcpy(array[0][0], username);
```

I have, in fact, added a reference to `stdlib.h`

Comment: @Sinatr `string[,]` is a rectangular array, not a jagged one.

Comment: You could create a two-dimensional array of `std:string`

Comment: @MatthewWatson It won't be in C.

Comment: @MatthewWatson std::string is a template in C++, not C. wrong language.

Comment: Oops yes, I misread that.

Comment: You want a two dimensional array of strings. I.e. either a tree-dimensional array of `char` or a two-dimensional array of `char*`, which you will have to allocate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code crashes as code is attempting to save `scanf()` input to the place pointed to by `username`, yet `username` is not initialized.

```
char *username;
scanf("%s", &username);  // bad
```

Instead, could use

```
char username[100];
scanf("%99s", username);
```

Or better

```
char username[100];
fgets(username, sizeof username, stdin);
username[strcspn(username, "\n")] = '\0';  // lop off potential \n
```

---

It appear OP wants a 50 x 7 array of pointers to C strings allocated like in `string[,] array = new string[50,7];`

Recall, in C, a string is itself a character array ending with a null character

```
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef char *a50_7_T[50][7];

a50_7_T *a50_7_alloc(void) {
  a50_7_T *a = malloc(sizeof *a);
  for (int i=0; i<50; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<7; j++) {
      (*a)[i][j] = NULL;  // or whatever OP wants as initial state
    }
  }
  return a;
}

void a50_7_free(a50_7_T *a) {
  for (int i=0; i<50; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<7; j++) {
      free((*a)[i][j]);
    }
  }
  free(a);
}

// Sample usage code
#include <string.h>
void foo(void) {
  a50_7_T *a = a50_7_alloc();
  printf("Size %zu\n", sizeof *a);   // e.g. "Size 1400"
  (*a)[0][0] = strcpy(malloc(6), "Hello");
  a50_7_free(a);
}
```

---

OTOH if OP want to create the array as part of the declaration, what OP did was on the right track.

```
//                   Initialize all to zeros, (NULL)
char *array[50][7] = { 0 };
...
array[0][0] = strcpy(malloc(6), "Hello");
...
free(array[0][0]);
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no easy way :) Since C has no high level string class, at least not without invoking some non-standard library.

To be flexible you would indeed need a 2D array of pointers `char *array[50][7];`, where every pointer is set to point at the actual string. Upon creating a string, you will have to allocate enough memory to hold it, plus the null terminator, by using malloc(). For example:

```
array[x][y] = malloc(strlen(the_string) + 1);
assert(array[x][y] != NULL);
```

It is not possible to copy strings in C with the `=` assignment operator, so after allocating the memory, you have to copy the string into the allocated memory area by using `strcpy`.

```
strcpy(array[x][y], the_string);
```

Comment: Your answer seems to be the most helpful but I cannot get it to work. See my edit in the OP.

Comment: @JimIliadis You have to allocate memory before storing something at that address...

Answer (score 1):

The array is ok as that. The problem may come from strings. C 'strings' are very low level, and can't really be compared to C# strings. You will have to manually allocate and deallocate space for them. If you plan on using scanf on them, you can allocate a buffer for each one, but you will have problems if you find a string longer than the buffer. You can assign them with '=', but only if you handle deallocation of the old value. Maybe you can check a library such as 'glib' to do some of the work for you.

Comment: To state clear: C does not have a string type. It is all convention.

Comment: Code cannot "You can assign them with '=', ".  In C, a _string_ is an array and array assignment does not exist.

Comment: @chux You are wrong. If you declare: `char *x[10][10]` you can do `x[0][0] = malloc(...);` or whatever.

Comment: `char *x[10][10]` declares a 2D array of pointers.  `malloc(...);` return a pointer.  `x[0][0] = malloc(...);` is an assignment of a pointer to a pointer.  It is not an assignment of an array to an array.  Pointer is not the same as array.

Comment: Thats the syntax the OP used to declare his array. And he can assign its elements with `=`, as he asked.

Comment: Yes, OP did `array[0][0] = malloc(strlen(username) + 1);` and code can assign elements of an array.  But this answer describes that as a string assignment with "can assign them with '='".  In C, this is not properly called a string assignment as it is a pointer assignment and strings are arrays, not pointers.  I suppose it comes down to if "them" meant a _string_ or a _pointer to a string_.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to decide two things where C# simply doesn't give you a choice (or at least, the standard one is *very* strongly recommended):

1. How do you want to represent your 2-dimensional array?

   You have the choice between, among others,

   - a single-dimensional array and explicit pointer-arithmetic,
   - a pointer to a 2-dimensional array with one fixed dimension,
   - a pointer to a 1-dimensional array of pointers to 1-dimensional arrays.
2. How do you want to represent your string?

   - Decide on the code-unit: `char` (hopefully 8-bit), `wchar16_t`, `wchar32_t`, `wchar_t`?
   - Counted strings or 0-terminated?
   - In a fixed-size-buffer or dynamically allocated?